# loop with pointer in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers

I was testing around with loops in c, and I came across a post about pointers in loops (`for(foo = bar; *foo; foo++)`).

I tried testing around with this knowledge, and made this:

```c
int main() {
   char a[9] = "test test";
   char *b; 
   for(b = a; *b; b++)
       printf("%c", *b);
   return 0; 
}
```

I compiled this (`gcc test.c`), then ran it and got the following output: `test test‼ aest test¶ ast test§ at test▬ a test↨ atest↑ aest↓ ast→ ata∟ a aa`

I changed `char a[9]` to `char a[10]`, assuming it had something to do with `\0`, then got `test testest testst testt test testtesteststt`.

Why does this happen? I thought that this loop would end after 9 cycles, as there are 9 characters in the string provided.

Comment: You are hitting undefined behavior

Comment: Well, now the question doesn't make any sense, since you silently fixed the error in the program while the rest of the question still complains about the unexpected output.

Comment: read the line after "i compiled this" and the solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you problem is here

```
char a[9] = "test test";
```

`"test test"` as a c string takes 10 bytes: 9 for the characters and one for the terminating `'\0'` character.

Do:

```
char a[] = "test test";
```

Ie. let the compiler work out how much memory the string takes.

Why is this an issue?

Because the C runtime detects the end of a string when it sees a `'\0'` character. You have not got one, so the runtime code runs off the end of the string and keeps going till it hits a `'\0'`

Also you should do

```
 printf("%s\n", b);
```

so that each loop prints on one line. Do not do `printf(<string>)` this is asking for trouble

OK, next question is - why doesnt it just print `"test test"`.

```
 char a[9] = "test test";
 char *b; 
 for(b = a; *b; b++)
     printf("%s\n",b);
 return 0;
```

Let's do the first loop. At the print statement:

- `b` is a char pointer pointing at the first `'T'` in the string
- `printf("%s\n", b)` will print the *string* starting at that point, ie `"Test Test"`

Second loop, same place

- `b` now points at the `'e'` character
- `printf("%s\n", b)` will print the *string* starting at that point, ie `"est Test"`

Third

- `b` now points at the `'s'` character
- `printf("%s\n", b)` will print the *string* starting at that point, ie `"st Test"`

All clear?

If you want to print the string char by char do

```
 char a[9] = "test test";
 char *b; 
 for (b = a; *b; b++)
     printf("%c\n", *b);
 return 0;
```

That `printf` says 'print one character, the character pointed at by b.'

Comment: I did this, and i get `test testest testst testt test testtesteststt`. Why doesn't it stop at the end of the string? Is something else wrong?

Comment: I tried this, and got the same thing, but in different lines. I'd want this to stop at the end of the string, printing out nothing other than `test test`.

Comment: so you wanted one character at a time? use %c instead of %s and *b instead of b in the printf... `printf("%c",*b);`

Comment: Oh, you mean your loop is trying to print one character each time, instead of the remainder of the string from each position?  Well, you should have said that in your question.  You can use `printf("%c", *b);` or `fputc(*b, stdout);`

Comment: @Sid ok you didnt say that - will update the answer

Comment: Got it, thanks! I completely gazed over the fact that I was printing the entire string, I apologize.